# List of frequencies that a device can connect to over 2.4 and 5 GHz channels

Tags: ieee-802.11, networking

When connecting to a Wifi on 2.4GHz or 5GHz channel, a device connects on a certain **frequency**. Is there a somewhere list of all possible frequencies that a device can connect to on a **2.4GHz/5GHz channel**?

Looking a [this link](https://www.sqimway.com/wifi_band.php), I am thinking by looking at the list that following is the list of frequencies that a device could latch on to?

**2.4 GHz**

```
2412    
2417    
2422    
2427    
2432    
2437    
2442    
2447    
2452    
2457    
2462    
2467    
2472    
2484
```

**5 GHz**

```
5180    
5200    
5220    
5240    
5260    
5280    
5300    
5320    
5500    
5520    
5540    
5560    
5580    
5600    
5620    
5640    
5660    
5680    
5700    
5720    
5745    
5765    
5785    
5805    
5825
```

Is the above list complete or are there more frequencies that could be used? If there is more, then is there an official link where I can get this information?

I know that for 2.4GHz the frequency would lie between `2412` to `2484` GHz. And for 5GHz, it lies between `5170` to `5825` GHz. Could the frequency be a random number between the ranges or is it a defined set of numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If there is more, then is there an official link where I can get this
> information?

The official source is the IEEE 802.11 working group. You can download some IEEE standards for free with a simple registration as part of the [IEEE Get program](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/browse/standards/get-program/page).

The 802.11-2016 standard is available through GET program here: [GET 802(R) Standards](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/browse/standards/get-program/page/series?id=68)

But you will also find useful information in the wikipedia page [List of WLAN channels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels).

> Could the frequency be a random number between the ranges or is it a
> defined set of numbers?

No. You will see that WiFi channels use channels that are centered on specific frequencies and have a defined width (range)

for example for 2.4Ghz those values are:

[image]
Source: the wikipedia page linke above.

Comment: The 5 GHz list is longer than what I expected but again some of the frequencies are not allowed in some countries. Thanks for the information

Answer (score 2):

> Could the frequency be a random number between the ranges or is it a
> defined set of numbers?

When you transmit information (*i.e.* modulate a carrier frequency), you transmit signals that spread in a range of frequencies.  This is what we call *bandwidth* or frequency range in the chart that @JFL posted.  You don't just transmit on one frequency.

In the US, the Federal Communications Commission (FCC) regulates radio transmissions (I believe it's CISPR in the EU).  In the Industrial, Scientific and Medical (ISM) bands, as long as you stay within certain power limits and don't intentionally interfere with someone, you can do almost anything you want (microwave ovens operate in this band).  So you don't *have* to transmit on specific frequencies, but if you want someone to listen to you, you have to agree on where to listen.  That's why there are designated "channels." in the band.